# What is the meaning of char *in_str after function parameters and before function body?

Tags: c, pthreads

I was going through **Pthreads Programming** by Bradford Nichols, on Page number **177** I noticed this code:

```
 static char work_buffer[100];
 void reverse_string(in_str)
 char *in_str;
 {
   ...
   ...
 }
```

What is the third line of code doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third line states that the parameter `in_star` of `reverse_string` is of type `char *`. Its an old K&R style of parameter declaration.

Comment: is this still supported by modern compilers?

Comment: @InQusitive; Yes. Most of the compilers like GCC still support this.

Comment: C2011 still treats it as mandatory-to-implement (section 6.9.1) although considered obsolescent (section 6.11.7).

Comment: It is certainly an anachronism in code written for pthreads, though!